# Probability of RANDOMIZED-QUICKSORT exceed worst case

Tags: algorithm

The question is from clrs (exercise 12.4-5)

> **Consider RANDOMIZED-QUICKSORT operating on a sequence of n input numbers.
>   Prove that for any constant k > 0, all but O(1/n^k) of the n! input permutations 
>   yield an O(n lg n) running time.**

How can I build the model of worst case, and get the max bound of it.

Comment: i asked the [same question at CS stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/86149/how-to-bound-the-probability-that-quicksort-takes-greater-than-n-lg-n-time/86150?noredirect=1#comment184765_86150), and worked out a pretty satisfactory solution with the help of another user.